# How can I make three plotly guage chart in same row?

Tags: plotly, subplot

I have follow the reference here:
[enter link description here](https://plotly.com/python/indicator/)

but once i altered the "grid" from from 2x2 to 3x3 , it come out a mess

```
>  fig.update_layout(
>         grid = {'rows': 3, 'columns': 3, 'pattern': "independent"},
>         template = {'data' : {'indicator': [{
>             'title': {'text': "Speed"},
>             'mode' : "number+delta+gauge",
>             }]
>                             }})
```

and for subplot, it seems it didnt support indicator type,i got error when trying to use subplot

```
ValueError: Trace type 'indicator' is not compatible with subplot type 'xy' at grid position (1, 1) See the docstring for the specs argument to plotly.subplots.make_subplots for more information on subplot types
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want all four traces from the example you provided to be in the same *one* row.

In that case, you should instead pass `grid = {'rows': 1, 'columns': 3, 'pattern': "independent"}` to the `fig.update_layout` method with 1 row instead of 3.

Then you also need to change the `domain` parameter of each trace accordingly (row 0, column 0, ... row 0, column 2), similar to how you would loop through a 2D array.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Indicator(
    value = 200,
    delta = {'reference': 160},
    gauge = {
        'axis': {'visible': False}},
    domain = {'row': 0, 'column': 0}))

## domain needs to be adjusted relative to the placement of other traces
fig.add_trace(go.Indicator(
    value = 120,
    gauge = {
        'shape': "bullet",
        'axis' : {'visible': False}},
    domain = {'x': [0, 0.38], 'y': [0.10, 0.30]}))

fig.add_trace(go.Indicator(
    mode = "number+delta",
    value = 300,
    domain = {'row': 0, 'column': 1}))

fig.add_trace(go.Indicator(
    mode = "delta",
    value = 40,
    domain = {'row': 0, 'column': 2}))

fig.update_layout(
    grid = {'rows': 1, 'columns': 3, 'pattern': "independent"},
    template = {'data' : {'indicator': [{
        'title': {'text': "Speed"},
        'mode' : "number+delta+gauge",
        'delta' : {'reference': 90}}]
                         }})

fig.show()
```

[image]